# Kendo UI grid column editable false using GridColumnSettings

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid like this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GridView.DataSource)
    .Name("grid").Columns(columns => columns.LoadSettings(Model.GridView.ColumnSettings))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))   
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add User"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("OnGridRead", "Manage"))  
    )
)
```

And I'm using Kendo **GridColumnSettings** to define the columns in my model which is a GridView(Model) here like below.

```
 public class GridView 
    {
        public List<GridColumnSettings> ColumnSettings
        {
            get
            {
                var items = new List<GridColumnSettings>
                            {
                                new GridCommandColumnSettings
                                {
                                    Commands =
                                    {
                                        new GridEditActionCommand()
                                    },
                                    Width = "70px"
                                },
                                new GridColumnSettings
                                {
                                    Member = "Id",
                                    Hidden = true
                                },
                                new GridColumnSettings
                                {
                                    Member = "FirstName"
                                },
                                new GridColumnSettings
                                {
                                    Member = "LastName"
                                },
                                new GridColumnSettings
                                {
                                    Member = "UserName"                                

                                },
                                new GridColumnSettings
                                {
                                    Member = "Password",
                                    ClientTemplate = "***",

                                }

                            };

                return items;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here I need to disable Username field only in inline edit mode of the grid.
Currently there is no property available in GridColumnSettings class as `editable`. How can I disable the **username** field in edit mode of the grid using **GridColumnSettings** class.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the below code snippet. I have disabled the StudentID field in below demo.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.Student>()
    .Name("Grid")
        //.Columns(columns =>
        //   {
        //       columns.Bound(c => c.StudentID);
        //       columns.Bound(c => c.StudentName);
        //   })
     .Columns(cols => cols.LoadSettings(ViewBag.cols))
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)).ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
       .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Home"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
              .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
             .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.StudentID);
            model.Field(p => p.StudentID).Editable(true);
        })
        )
)
```

Method 1:-

```
<script>
    function onEdit(e) {
        if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
            $(e.container).find("input[name='StudentID']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Method 2:-

```
<script>
    function onEdit(e) {
        if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
           $(e.container).find("input[name='StudentID']").parent().html($(e.container).find("input[name='StudentID']").val()).removeAttr('data-container-for');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Method worked for me.
But i also think it only will happen when you are not specifying the model explicitly while binding grid whether its MVVM or not. 
As an alternative, i added model in kendo datasource and mention field as "editable: false" and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Please try below solution to disable the username field in edit mode of the grid.

```
 .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.UserName).Editable(false);
        })
```

Comment: I tried it but It disable the username field in the Insert mode also

Comment: Yes you are correct, It will disable the username field in the Insert mode also. But the same case will be applicable for the GridColumnSettings class. I tried with the 'Visible' property in this class.